# Correct way of using FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was recently advised to use flat list instead of map

In Map, I was doing something like this in **`render`**  (this works)

```
let CryptoData = this.props.cryptoLoaded;
let displaySearchCrypto = []
      displayCrypto = CryptoData.map(el => {
          return (<CoinCard
            no={i++}
            key={el["short"]}
            coinShortName = {el["short"]}
            coinName = {el["long"]}
            coinPrice = {el["price"].toFixed(2)}
            marketCap = {(el["mktcap"]/1000000000).toFixed(4)}
            percentChange = {el["perc"].toFixed(2)}
            vwapData={el["vwapData"].toFixed(2)}
            coinImage={"https://coincap.io/images/coins/" + el["long"] + ".png"}
            />
          )
        })
      }
```

Following the very minimal example for  FlatList in the React Native Website, I did something like this in my **`return`**

```
   <FlatList
               data={this.props.cryptoLoaded}
               renderItem={({ el }) => (
               <CoinCard
                key={el["short"]}
                coinShortName = {el["short"]}
                coinName = {el["long"]}
                coinPrice = {el["price"].toFixed(2)}
                marketCap = {(el["mktcap"]/1000000000).toFixed(4)}
                percentChange = {el["perc"].toFixed(2)}
                vwapData={el["vwapData"].toFixed(2)}
                coinImage={"https://coincap.io/images/coins/" + el["long"] + ".png"}
                />
        )}
      />
```

But this is throwing an error saying that `short` is not defined. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here? How do we properly use FlatList?

Comment: There is no need to use `key` prop since `Flatlist` handles it with the help of `keyExtractor`.

Comment: Have you console.log the out renderItem? You're destructuring the { el } parameter. Have you tri coinShortName={short} instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renderItem` callback gets an object with the `item` property, so you need to change your destructuring to `renderItem={({item}) => <Cmp prop={item["short"]}/>}`.